# How to use a column alias in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use a column alias in the query of another subquery.

In the example below, I want the alias *dobirth* to be fed into the next query so that it can be used to get the difference between the date of birth and today's date to extract the age.

```
SELECT
MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'enrolment_id' THEN (
    SELECT dobirth FROM wp_sp_enrolments E WHERE OIM.meta_value=E.id) END) as 'dobirthc',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),'dobirthc')), '%Y')+0 AS 'Age',
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items O;
```

When running the above query I get:

```
Unknown column 'dobirthc' in 'field list'
```

Comment: If you run your query, them mysql tells you if your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your query -

- table ref `OIM` not in FROM cluase
- comma after 'Age' but no following expression

You can refer back to the existing alias by `SELECT`ing it. Instead of -

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),'dobirthc')), '%Y')+0 AS 'Age',
```

you can use -

```
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, `dobirthc`)), '%Y')+0) AS Age,
/* or */
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, (SELECT `dobirthc`))), '%Y')+0 AS Age,
```